If a $\Pi_1$ sentence is proven undecidable in PA, can I add its negation to the axioms?
I know that a sentence $P$ that is independent from a certain axiomatic system $S$ can be added to the axioms without affecting the consistency of the system, and so can its negation. If $P$ is a $\Pi_1^0$ sentence, though, from its undecidability in $S$ it would follow its truth (since if it was false you could disprove it with a counterexample, and thus it wouldn't be undecidable).
So, can I add its negation $\neg P$ to $S$? Wouldn't that contradict $S$ in some way, since if $\neg P$, a counterexample should exist, which does not? How would that work? Also, what can we say about $\mathrm{Con}(S + \neg P)$?

Hi, welcome to MSE! Are you familiar with the completeness theorems? In this case "true" means "holds in $\Bbb N$", not "is provable from PA" (ie "holds in every model of PA"). So when you add the negation of such a true sentence you get a consistent theory, but $\Bbb N$ isn't a model of this theory. In particular, in each model of this theory a counterexample does exist, but this counterexample lies outside of the "standard part". If (a part of) that still doesn't make sense, can you say which bit?
